# Overwrite APEX language elements

Tags: html, jquery, oracle-apex

Oracle APEX version 20.1.0.00.13. has a problem rendering day names on calendar region, where it displays ??? where day names supposed to be, and if I change the language, so that it is not serbian, then day names appear (Mon, Tue, Wen...). To me is seems obvious that language package is incomplete. I came up with idea to write some jquery and assign day names when the page loads.

```
$('fc-fri').children()[0].innerText = 'Friday'
```

But this might affect the performance, but beside that I believe there is a better ways to do this. Perhaps the conventional ways which I don't know yet.

How do I overwrite language components in APEX?

Comment: "when I change the language"... what does that mean ? Without telling *exactly which* language is showing the issue it is hard to reproduce your issue... When does it work, when does it not work ? Please update your question with as much info as possible that allows other users to replicate your issue. Also pls add your apex version.

Comment: serbian language has this issue. APEX version 20.1.0.00.13.

Comment: Pls put this information in your question, not in the comments. As I said "as much info as possible". Explain *exactly* what your settings are, give an example (possibly on sample data) that allows users to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You mean, the days of the week are not getting translated to Serbian?